# Merge 'deodex' with 'odex'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Both tags ([odex](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odex) and [deodex](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deodex)) cover each 2 questions currently. As one is just the opposite of the other, bot both deal with the same issue, I'd suggest making `deodex` a synonym to `odex` by merging the two -- as it once was done with "lockscreen" and "unlock-screen".

Comment: Would the tag wikis then be combined?

Comment: I suggest to keep the tag wiki of `deodex`. It includes all what the wiki of `odex` has, plus a little more.

Comment: Sounds good to me even though they are antonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine to me. [odex](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odex) seems perfectly capable of handling questions related to de-odexed ROMs and the like, and the number of questions in these tags is pretty small anyway.